# How to serve cached pages to first time visitors?

Tags: caching

Is there a way to cache pages from previous visitors and then share that cashe to first time visitors?

I know this can't be done on client side but not sure about sever side of things.

I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction and maybe some resources as I can't find find much on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's how page caching works in general. Your site code will do something like this:

```
look in the cache for this page
if (it's in the cache) {
    serve it
} else {
    generate the page
    store the page in the cache
    serve it
}
```

So, the very first visitor to the page will cause it to be cached, and then all subsequent visitors will get the cached version. This can be done at the application level (i.e., via code written by you or perhaps some library you're using) or at the server level, like with [`Squid`](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Alex Howansky, that makes sense. One follow up question if a may... I have some keywords and files inserted dynamically using url variables, would these have to be excluded from the cache to serve this content?

Comment: Depends -- if you want the content to be different for every visitor, then yes, exclude those pages. If it's ok for the content to be the same for repeated page loads, then cache it. Note you may also approach this by shortening the time-to-cache for those pages. E.g., a standard page may stay in the cache for a day or a week before it's considered stale and regenerated, while maybe you set some other pages to time out after only an hour.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I understand everything I need to do now.